# DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code? I am new in vb.net development hence taking some reference codes online & tried to write this code but getting error. Please tell me where I am doing wrong & correct my code.

ERROR
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblId.Text) Then
            Dim query As String = "Select ID, email From users where ID=@id"
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblId.Text)
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                'Do Login Code here
                Try
                    Dim str As String = "select * from users where ID='" + lblId.Text + "';"
                    Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
                    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2)
                    Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "users"
                    Response.Cookies("chkusername").Value = lblId.Text
                    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex)
                End Try
            Else
                Try
                    Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO users (ID, DP, displayName) values('" + lblId.Text + "', '" + ProfileImage.ImageUrl.ToString + "', '" + lblName.Text + "')"
                    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
                    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
                    command.CommandText = str1
                    command.Connection = con
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex)
                End Try

            End If
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You are using the same connection for two nested commands. As far as I know with MySql you need two separate connections

Comment: The DataReader must be closed before you execute any other SQL command (`select * from users.., INSERT INTO users...`) within the same connection.

Comment: @Steve can you post rectified answer please

Comment: @AlexB. Please post rectified answer

Comment: There are a variety of solutions for this issue found in the 'Related' panel on the right side of the page. Read through some and see if you can find one that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So no one given me solution I tried to resolve it from my own. Hence people suggested to close data reader but that was my question where I need to close data reader since I am a new developer. I closed my datareader in else clause before it's command gets executed..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblId.Text) Then
            Dim query As String = "Select ID, email From users where ID=@id"
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblId.Text)
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                'Do Login Code here
                Try
                    Dim str As String = "select * from users where ID='" + lblId.Text + "';"
                    Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
                    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2)
                    Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "users"
                    Response.Cookies("chkusername").Value = lblId.Text

                    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex)
                End Try
            Else
                Try
                    Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO users (ID, DP, displayName) values('" + lblId.Text + "', '" + ProfileImage.ImageUrl.ToString + "', '" + lblName.Text + "')"
                    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
                    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
                    dr.Close()
                    command.CommandText = str1
                    command.Connection = con
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex)
                End Try

            End If
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Stack community now getting worst. The moderators are arrogant